# Unexpected JavaScript return type

Tags: javascript

Can somebody tell me why these two functions give different outputs? Why does one give 'undefined' and the other one give 'object'?

```js
function aaa(){
  return 
  {
    test: 1
  };
}

console.log(typeof aaa());

function abc(){
  return {test: 1};
}

console.log(typeof abc());
```

Comment: Try using ```return``` with parenthesis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return 
{
}
```

is interpreted as

```
return;
{
}
```

Thus it returned `undefined`.

```js
function aaa(){
  return {
    test: 1
  };
}

console.log(typeof aaa());

function abc(){
  return {test: 1};
}

console.log(typeof abc());
```